# I'm not getting the value inside the textbox

Tags: angular6

`<input type="text" class="form-control input-md"  #S="ngModel"   required [(ngModel)]="address.studentDetails[i].sem"  value="Q1" placeholder="SEM" name="{{[i]}}+sem" minlength="2"  maxlength="2"  style="margin-right:2%;width:80%;border-radius: 5px;">` 
Here i m trying to display value inside the text box, but i m not getting the value. anyone please help me.

Comment: do you get an error in the console? if you share a minimal stackblitz, it'll be easier to help

Comment: No, i did not get any error in console.

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. Please give this a read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask